# Create database from prestored db file on SDcard

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sd-card

The database i want to import is over 5Mb. When i put the .db in asset folder i got some errors. So i split the database into smaller db files and assemble the pieces to create the database. So is there any way i can import the database from sdcard and start using the db without splitting and assembling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `assets` folder has a size restriction on some files, but not `.jpg`, `.mp3`. You can simply name the database file as `yourdb.db.jpg` and Android won't complain.. Hope that helps as a quick & easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:
place the database file inside the sdcard then create a method inside a class, the method is like:

```
public class DB_Path {
    public final SQLiteDatabase getOrders() {
            File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/TheDataBaseFile");
            SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
                 return db;
        }
}
-----------------------
```

initialize like

```
public DB_Path dbp = new DB_Path();
    public SQLiteDatabase db = dbp.getOrders();
```

after that you can call the cursor with db.

```
  Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("the sql query",null);
```

Comment: I also took some time to sort this out, good it saved your time :)